# How can I tell if an ETF is sufficiently liquid?

Tags: etf, liquidity

How can I tell if an ETF is sufficiently liquid? How much should it have in assets? How much should the minimum average daily volume be?

Comment: sufficiently liquid for what?

Comment: To make it safe enough to buy, so that we know we can sell it when we need to.

Comment: All large- and mid-cap funds are just about guaranteed to be liquid, by the very fact that liquidity flows naturally flows naturally size.

Comment: Thanks, Ron, but is a more generalized answer possible? Is there a known threshold that experienced investors use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lower levels of liquidity lead to greater bid-ask spreads.

Liquidity is affected by:

- ETF composition
- The trading volume of the components
- And to some degree, the trading volume of the ETF
- The sector that the ETF emulates
- The risk of the components (narrow versus broad based)